# Verify if 'Ajax Loading' image is shown or not

Tags: c#, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I Have 2 dropdown lists named dd1 and dd2.

dd1 is for Country and dd2 is for States.

On click of dd1, an ajax call happens (and 'loading' image is displayed) and dd2 is filled.

Is there a way to identify that the 'loading' image was shown after clicking dd1?

So the test case goes like this.
1. GoTo a PAGE
2. Select 'USA' in dd1 
   - Assert if the loading image is visible
   - Assert if the loading image is gone
3. Select 'Texas'

I am struck at the Assertion at 2nd step

Comment: add your code here..so we can solve..

Comment: Basically the image is an HTML element which can be handled. You can check whether that element gets disappear or Please post the HTML of that image (loading symbol). So that anyone can get you the code.

Comment: HTML of the image  <img src="/images/usercontrols/common/progress-bar.gif" alt="progress bar" style="margin: 0 auto;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

wait.Until(driver => !driver.FindElement(By.Id("ControlId").Displayed);

Answer (score 0):

Put your loading image in an span or div and give it an Id.
Once your dd1 is changed, make the Ajax call and also show it.
any time you wanted to know whether or not loading box is there, try to 
check the visibility

```
$("logoContainer").is(":visible")
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a driver override so now I call **driver.WaitForPageLoad();** and it waits till the spinner is gone and the document ready status is loaded.  More details can be seen in the example link but here is how you override and wait till spinner is gone (assuming spinner has a class you can search on.

[Example](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2013/09/webdriver-wait-for-document-ready-and.html)

```
public static bool WaitForPageLoad(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    WaitForDocumentReady(driver);
    bool ajaxReady = WaitForAjaxReady(driver);
    WaitForDocumentReady(driver);

    return ajaxReady;
}

private static bool WaitForAjaxReady(IWebDriver driver)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    return wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
    {
        return driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".waiting, .tb-loading")).Count == 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, my intention is not to wait for the wait image to load. My intention is to check whether it was visible (even for 1 millisecond) or not. The code which you gave will give a FALSE POSITIVE if the image did not load at all. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In that case, you'll still want a WebDriverWait but instead of waiting till the class goes away (count == 0), you want to wait till the element exists and is visible.  return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("css selection string")).Displayed;